# How to manage 2 column mega menu drop down without plugin

Tags: wordpress

**Is There any custom code for creating 2 column mega menu without plugin. 
please help me**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage Mega menu by below code :

```
<?php
               $menu_name = 'primary';
               $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
               $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
               $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );               
?>
                     <ul class="nav">
                         <?php
                         $count = 0;
                         $submenu = true;

                         foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
                             // set up title and url
                             $title = $item->title;
                             $link = $item->url;

                             // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
                             if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):

                             // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
                             $parent_id = $item->ID;
                         ?>

                         <li>
                             <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
                                 <span><?php echo $title; ?></span>
                             </a>
                         <?php endif; ?> 

                            <?php if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ): ?>
                              <?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>
                                 <div class="mega-menu sub-menu-columns">
                                  <div class="mega-bg">
                                    <div class="mega-mrg">

                                  <div class="maga-half">
                                  <ul>
                                 <?php endif; ?>
                                  <li><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></a></li>
                                  <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ): ?>
                                 </ul>                                 
                                  </div>

                               </div>  
                               </div>
                               </div>  

                                <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>
                                 <?php endif; ?>       

                              <?php if (@$menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ): ?>
                         </li>                           
                         <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

                     <?php $count++; endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Hope this work for you.